# Checking for both NaT or pandas timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I validate for NaT in python while at the same time working for timestamps. E.g. the variable `_date` can be either `NaT` or `Timestamp('2017-12-02 00:00:00')`

If I use this: `np.isnat(np.datetime64(_date))`, it works for `Timestamp('2017-12-02 00:00:00')` but not `NaT`

Comment: I guess you want 3 categories:  valid time (timestamp), invalid time (NaT), and other (string, int, etc.).  I'm not sure if that's possible, at least in the way you are specifically asking.  It would be better if you would create a sample array or dataframe (as @Gullan does in their answer) and then show desired results.

Comment: Note that the answer here depends on if the array or series has dtype of datetime or is of mixed (object) dtype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `isna` or `fillna` method on it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time = pd.Series(['2017-12-02 20:40:30','2017-12-02 00:00:00',np.nan])
time = time.apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x))
print(time)
0   2017-12-02 20:40:30
1   2017-12-02 00:00:00
2                   NaT


time.isna()

0    False
1    False
2     True


time.fillna("missing")

0    2017-12-02 20:40:30
1    2017-12-02 00:00:00
2                missing
```

Comment: Note btw that `isna` will be false for NaN and NaT.  It's not specific for time whereas np.nat is (I think).  I'm not really sure what OP is asking though.  This answer seems like a good start, at least!

Answer (score 0):

By using `to_datetime`

```
time=pd.to_datetime(time)
time
Out[1131]: 
0   2017-12-02 20:40:30
1   2017-12-02 00:00:00
2                   NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```